# Jquery fadeIn is not working

Tags: jquery, html, click, fade

i was writing a html page and then I have this div:

```
<div id = "insert" class="new">
```

and the style of this div:

```
 .new {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    display:none;
    }
```

So, i tried to use FadeIn() and make this div appear, but it won't work! here is the jquery i've written:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
$("#insert").fadeIn();
});
```

"add" is the ID of the button to be clicked.
Do you guys know what's the problem going on?

Comment: Have you tried writing "fadeIn" instead of "FadeIn"?

Comment: you div height and width is not correct, the div height is zero. so you can see the div.

Answer (score 0):

your div height and width is not correct, the div height is zero. so you can see the div.

if you want more smooth animation you can give `fadeIn(time in milliseconds)` parameter.

more info can be get [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#insert").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: none;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="insert" class="new"></div>
  <button id='add'>add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is wrong:

```
$("#add").click(function(){ $("#insert").fadeIn(); });
```

What is "#insert"? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/su6wxp8q/1/

And yes the DIV is empty and has no height defined.

Comment: `#insert` is the id of the div with class `.new`, mentioned in the question.